# How can I retrieve template id from docusign envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I have created a DocuSign envelope from template. I have stored the **envelope id** for future operations. Using this **envelope id** I can only retrieve the envelope that I have created but I need the **template id** too. Is there any way to retrieve the **template id** from envelope or FolderItems? Please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you create an envelope from a Template if the `templateId` is saved as meta data anywhere in the envelope (I don't believe it is).  As such you can simply do that yourself - try using **Envelope Custom Fields** to store the `templateId` at the time of creation, and that `templateId` will then be stored as meta data on that envelope throughout it's lifecycle.

Do a search in the DocuSign API Documentation to find out more about "Envelope Custom Fields".  For example, [here](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Add%20Envelope%20Custom%20Fields%20to%20an%20Envelope.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____49) is the page for how to create them.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Ergin. I have tried to implement your idea and it is working. But there are some other issues whatever I have done. I am sharing some parts of my code.

```
//Getting available folder list of my DocuSign account.
DocuSignServiceRef.AvailableFolders folders = DocuSignHelper.GetDocuSignServiceClient().GetFolderList(new DocuSignServiceRef.FoldersFilter { AccountId = DocuSignHelper.UserID });

//Creating a FolderFilter item to get folder items using this filter.
DocuSignServiceRef.FolderFilter filter = new DocuSignServiceRef.FolderFilter();
filter.AccountId = DocuSignHelper.UserID;
filter.FolderTypeInfo = new DocuSignServiceRef.FolderTypeInfo();
filter.FolderTypeInfo = folders.Folders[1].FolderTypeInfo; //Filter Send Items

//Getting sent items
DocuSignServiceRef.FolderResults results = DocuSignHelper.GetDocuSignServiceClient().GetFolderItems(filter);

if (results != null && results.ResultSetSize > 0)
{
    foreach (DocuSignServiceRef.FolderItem item in results.FolderItems)
    {
        foreach (DocuSignServiceRef.RecipientStatus recipient in item.RecipientStatuses)
        {
            //Filtering items by Recipient
            if (recipient.Email.Equals(RecipientEmail))
            {   
                //Getting envelope of the folder item
                DocuSignServiceRef.Envelope sentEnvelope = DocuSignHelper.GetDocuSignServiceClient().RequestEnvelope(item.EnvelopeId, false);
                if (sentEnvelope.CustomFields != null)
                {
                    //Checking envelope's custom fields for template id
                    foreach (DocuSignServiceRef.CustomField customField in sentEnvelope.CustomFields)
                    {
                        if (string.Equals(customField.Name, "TemplateID"))
                        {
                            if (customField.Value == "{CurrentTemplateID}")
                            {
                                HasAlreadySignedSameTemplate = true;
                                //I will not request the recipient for another signature on same template.
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is working for me. But it is taking too much time to load all Sent items. I can't see any way to set recipient information in FolderFilter. If I can set the recipient's email in filter at the first while I am loading Sent Items then time will be saved for me. Otherwise this code will get unusable.

Have you any idea about modifying my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating envelopes with a REST call you can retrieve the info with a call `templatesv2/accounts/:accountId/envelopes/:envelopeId/templates`
Have a go [in the envelope tab](https://iodocs.docusign.com/). I noticed that envelopes created with a SOAP sdk don't have this information filled in.